# Saving scrbook as 2up PDF

Tags: pdfpages, printing, scrbook

I have a document of the scrbook documentclass, so it distinguishes between even and odd pages. I want to save it as a handout (PDF) with two pages per a4 side, placing the even side to the left and the odd side to the right (so it looks like an opened book). Is there any good option for making this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your book is something like

```
% mybook.tex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\title{My Great Masterpiece}
\author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Foo}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

you can simply use `pdfpages` as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{mybook}
\clearpage\null
\includepdf[pages={{},3-},nup=2x1]{mybook}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The important point is the option

```
pages={{},3-},nup=2x
```

which means 1) insert an empty page (the `{}`) and then 2) all pages from the third on.

Comment: Thank you so much @campa.